# Ag Grid partial cell formatting - e.g. how to have some text in a cell styled - bold, italic, colored (but not other text)

Tags: reactjs, formatting, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In a simple HTML table, if I want to apply text formatting to a portion in a cell, such as:

```
<td>Qty: <b>5</b></td>
```

It's very simple to make part of the text bold, and part of it not. I've looked through a bunch of Ag Grid docs, and I'm not seeing a simple way to do that.
(I'd prefer not to need a cell renderer component for this; just a simple method using a value-formatter.)

Here's some of what I've looked at, but it doesn't provide such:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-content/

https://blog.ag-grid.com/conditional-formatting-for-cells-in-ag-grid/

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-formatters/

I'm hoping there's a way like:

```
valueFormatter(params) {
   return 'Qty: <b>' + params.value + '</b>';
},
```

But I've tried that, and it doesn't interpret/format using the HTML tags.

Comment: you cant use html tags like that, you have to use cellStyle, cellClass or cellClassRules to achieve this

Comment: I only want part of the text in the cell formatted though.

Comment: then use `cellRenderer` if you just want the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this; it uses the cellRenderer, but does not require a separate component - it can be defined directly from the columnDefs:

```
  {
    field: 'ItemID',
    headerName: 'Item ID',
    cellRenderer: params => `<b>ID:</b> ${params.data.ItemID}`,
  },
```

[image: Example]

This lets you provide minor selective formatting directly within the columnDefs, without needing to create a separate relatively mundane component for each field. Makes the code shorter, faster to write, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Great, that's definitely better for small renderers.

Answer (score 1):

Value formatter can do only string formatting. You have to use cell renderer, as described [in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/). For example:

`myRenderer.jsx`:

```
export default props => {
   const cellValue = props.valueFormatted ?? props.value;

   return (
       <span>Qty: <b>{cellValue}</b></span>
   );
}
```

`gridComponent.jsx`:

```
import MyRenderer from './myRenderer.jsx';
/* ... */
<AgGridReact frameworkComponents={{ myRenderer: MyRenderer }}>
  <AgGridColumn field="qty" cellRenderer="myRenderer" />
</AgGridReact>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way without requiring a separate component - something that could be defined directly in the column def, but it appears your answer is the correct / only way to achieve this with AG Grid. Thanks!

Comment: Found a better way to do something simple like this - see below.